# What is the merit criterion in Weka?

Tags: weka

I'm doing a project for my data mining class about attribute classification on Weka, but the problem is that I can't write the report that is associated to said project because I don't understand the concept of "merit", I know that it's supposed to be a scoring system for the chosen subset but I don't get what it means exactly (is more better?, worse?)
Thanks in advance for any replies

Comment: You mean attribute selection? In that case, a higher merit is better.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.